# Subsidiary buttons show up when hover over main button

Tags: html, button

Is it possible to create subsidiary buttons that will show when one hovers over or clicks on the main button?
So the main button could be "trains". And then when you hover over that button, 2 additional subsidiary buttons will show up, e.g. "train 1" and "train 2".

```
<div id="button_group">
    <button type = "button"  class = "Button" id="trains" > Trains </button> <br />
    <button type = "button"  class = "Button" id="train1" > Train 1 </button> <br />
    <button type = "button"  class = "Button" id="train2" > Train 2 </button> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, of course. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried working with ul & li. However, I am confused when to use which. I also think that I have to work with the " display:none" style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/m9vZn/

Add this CSS:

```
#train1, #train2 {
    display: none;
}
#button_group:hover > button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I wanted :)